# How can you force flocculation of weizen yeast?

Tags: cold-crash, hefeweizen

I'm trying to make a Kristallweizen. I'd like to get most of the flavor of the hefe weizen been with no yeast and, but don't have access to filtering right now. What would be the best method(s) to force flocculation of hefe weizen yeast?

I'm thinking about adding another high flocculating yeast in secondary and see if that helps bring the hefe yeast down, combined with a few days in cold crash. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's called Gelatin my friend. Works wonders. Otherwise, just lager it for a long time. It will settle out.

Answer (score 2):

I brewed something like this a couple of months ago.

Wait until first fermentation has calmed down (not stopped), then rack to secondary and add some sugar to make fermentation go one, depending on the amount of headspace you still have. Use 4g/l of headspace.

Let it sit at least two weeks so that fermentation is finished, you will see that there already will be a build up of yeast on the bottom of the fermenter (that is, if you have a transparent fermenter).

If you can cold crash, then use this method to get more yeast out of the beer.

If you can't cold crash, move your secondary to a cooler place for a couple of weeks, so that yeast can drop out further.

Even after cold crashing or storing at a cooler place, there will be enough yeast in the beer for carbonation. Bottle, carbonate and then condition in a cool room.

It takes some time, but I was able to get a clear beer. It was actually a Leffe clone.

When pouring from the bottle, take care not to stir up the bottom.

Comment: I accidentally made a kristalweizen by leaving a hefeweizen in the fridge for three weeks while I went on holiday. Yeast was safale wb-06 and I was amazed how clear it was.